Evaluating a triple integral over an ellipsoid
I'm calculating this integral:
$\iiint_D \sqrt{(1-25z^2)(1-16y^2-25z^2)} dxdydz$
with $D=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+16y^2+25z^2 \leq 1 \}$
The change of variables $ (x,y,z) \rightarrow (\overline{x},\overline{y}/4,\overline{z}/5)$, so that $\overline{D}:  \overline{x}^2 + \overline{y}^2 + \overline{z}^2 \leq 1 $, gives:
$\iiint_\overline{D} \sqrt{(1-\overline{z}^2)(1-\overline{y}^2-\overline{z}^2)} d \overline{x} d \overline{y} d \overline{z}$
I thought the change to spherical coordinates would simplify it, but I'm stucked.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

$x=\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), 4y=\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$ and $5z=\cos(\phi)$ and do not forget the Jacobian.

I rather suggest cylindrical coordinates:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\iiint_{D}\sqrt{(1-25z^2)(1-16y^2-25z^2)}\,\mathrm d x\mathrm d y\mathrm d z\\
&=\frac{1}{20}\iiint_{\bar D}\sqrt{(1-\bar z^2)(1-\bar y^2-\bar z^2)}\,\mathrm d\bar x\mathrm d\bar y\mathrm d\bar z\\
&=\frac{1}{20}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-\rho^2\sin^2\Phi-z^2)}\,\rho\mathrm d\rho\mathrm dz\mathrm d\Phi\\
&=-\frac{1}{20}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-z^2}\left[\dfrac{(1-\rho^2\sin^2\Phi-z^2)^{3/2}}{3\sin^2\Phi}\right|_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\,\mathrm dz\mathrm d\Phi\\
&=-\frac{1}{20}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-z^2}\left[\dfrac{|\cos\Phi|^3(1-z^2)^{3/2}}{3\sin^2\Phi}-\dfrac{(1-z^2)^{3/2}}{3\sin^2\Phi}\right]\,\mathrm dz\mathrm d\Phi\\
&=\frac{1}{60}\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1-|\cos\Phi|^3}{\sin^2\Phi}\mathrm d\Phi}_{8}\underbrace{\int_{-1}^1 (1-z^2)^{2}\,\mathrm dz}_{16/15}=\boxed{\frac{32}{225}}
\end{aligned}$$
where the $1/20$ factor accounts for the $\mathbf x\to\bar{\mathbf x}$ substitution you made and corresponds to the jacobian
$\left|\dfrac{\partial\mathbf x}{\partial\bar{\mathbf x}}\right|$ .
